# Get mp3 & mp4 time length of file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube, rubygems, mp4

I'm using Rails 3.2+ and am wondering if there is an easy way to find out what the time length of a file is on my server.  For example if I had a video file in mp4 format, how would I find out that the length of the video is say 4 minutes 2 seconds long?  Same goes for mp3, or external sources like youtube/vimeo.  If there is a gem that does this that is fine as well, thanks.

Comment: mp3 file length is not easy to determine. you have to scan the entire file and count how many frames there are. each one is 0.028 seconds, but you have to account for VBR encoding (different byte size for each frame) and things like ID3 v1 and v2 tags, etc... You could approximate and say "ok, if this is a 128kbit mp3, then it's filesize/128kbit_size_of_frame * 0.028" long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For youtube/vimeo - https://github.com/thibaudgg/video_info

For video - https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

For mp3s - https://robinst.github.io/taglib-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

You will generally want to shell out, use some external program and parse its output. There are libraries that work this way, take a look at [RVideo](http://rvideo.rubyforge.org) or [Search for Video](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=video) on https://rubygems.org.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6, I think streamio-ffmpeg is the best solution to get time length for video and audio:
https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

stars: 1.5k

**first, you should install ffmpeg in your OS.**
then in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'
```

Then you can get all media infos you need: bitrate, duration, sample_rate... like this mp3 file.
[image: get a mp3 media info in rails]